# Can't delete table row at index after delete record in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'll start out by saying that I am VERY new to making apps in Xcode / Swift. I've never really done anything with Obj-C so Swift is really my first entry into coding for iOS.

My problem is that I am attempting to delete the table cell after deleting the Core Data record. I seem to be able to delete the Core data just fine, but get the same error every time I try to delete the cell row.

The error I'm getting is as follows:

> 2016-03-10 08:49:56.484 EZ List[31764:3225607] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.30.14/UITableView.m:1720
>   2016-03-10 08:49:56.487 EZ List[31764:3225607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
>   [... And so on]

And the code I'm using to delete is this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        // delete item at indexPath
        let request = self.fetchRequest()
        var fetchResults = [AnyObject]()

        do {
            fetchResults = try self.moc.executeFetchRequest(request)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Fetching Data to Delete Failed")
        }

        self.moc.deleteObject(fetchResults[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject)

        fetchResults.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

        do {
            try self.moc.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to Save after Delete")
        }

        self.lists.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)

    }

    let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Edit") { (action, indexPath) in
        // edit item at indexPath

    }

    edit.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 84/255, green: 200/255, blue: 214/255, alpha: 1)

    return [delete, edit]

}
```

After testing a bunch I have verified that the problem is with

```
self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
```

But I don't understand why it thinks the rows in sections are invalid. Any help would much appreciated. So far all my searching has come up with Obj-C answers or swift answers that don't seem to fix my problem.

EDIT:
Adding code for numberOfRowsInSection

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    if let sections = frc.sections {
        let currentSection = sections[section]
        return currentSection.numberOfObjects
    }

    return 0
}
```

EDIT2:
Here is the full code for my ViewController
**Keep in mind that I've been trying a few different things to get it to work so there are a few commented out things in there.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ListTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
var frc: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()
var lists : [Lists] = []

/*
var listNames: [String] = ["Any List", "Other List"]
var listItemCount: [Int] = [5, 6]
var listIcons: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "Generic List")!, UIImage(named: "Generic List")!]
*/

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "TableBackground"))
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
    self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    do {
        self.lists = try moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest()) as! [Lists]
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed setting lists array to fetch request")
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    checkAnyList()

    frc = getFCR()
    frc.delegate = self

    do {
        try frc.performFetch()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to perform inital fetch")
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    //self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = true

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    checkAnyList()

    frc = getFCR()
    frc.delegate = self

    do {
        try frc.performFetch()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to perform inital fetch")
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    if let sections = frc.sections {
        return sections.count
    }

    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    if let sections = frc.sections {
        let currentSection = sections[section]
        return currentSection.numberOfObjects
    }

    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let listCellReturn = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("listCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ListTableViewCell

    //let list = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Lists
    let list = self.lists[indexPath.row]

    listCellReturn.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 78, bottom: 0, right: 0)

    listCellReturn.listNameLabel.text = list.name
    listCellReturn.listIconImage.image = UIImage(data: (list.image)!)

    /*
    listCellReturn.listNameLabel.text = listNames[indexPath.row]
    listCellReturn.itemCountLabel.text = "Items: \(listItemCount[indexPath.row])"
    listCellReturn.listIconImage.image = listIcons[indexPath.row]
    */

    return listCellReturn
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        // delete item at indexPath
        let request = self.fetchRequest()
        var fetchResults = [AnyObject]()

        do {
            fetchResults = try self.moc.executeFetchRequest(request)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Fetching Data to Delete Failed")
        }

        self.moc.deleteObject(fetchResults[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject)

        fetchResults.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

        do {
            try self.moc.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to Save after Delete")
        }

        self.lists.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)

    }

    let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Edit") { (action, indexPath) in
        // edit item at indexPath

    }

    edit.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 84/255, green: 200/255, blue: 214/255, alpha: 1)

    return [delete, edit]

}

func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Lists")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    return fetchRequest

}

func getFCR() -> NSFetchedResultsController {

    frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    return frc

}

func checkAnyList() {

    var exists: Bool = false

    let fetchReq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Lists")
    let pred = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "name", "Any List")
    fetchReq.predicate = pred

    do {
        let check = try moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchReq)
        for rec in check {
            if let name = rec.valueForKey("name") {
                if (name as! String == "Any List") {
                    exists = true
                }
            }
        }

        if (exists == false) {
            let entityDesc = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Lists", inManagedObjectContext: moc)
            let list = Lists(entity: entityDesc!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)

            list.name = "Any List"
            list.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "Any List")!)

            do {
                try moc.save()
            } catch {
                fatalError("New list save failed")
            }
        }
    } catch {
        fatalError("Error checking for Any List")
    }

        //let check = try moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchReq)
        //for rec in check {

        //} catch {

}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}
*/

// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call...

```
self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
```

...when your data source has been changed. When you call the above method, it asks your tableView's delegate how many rows in that section, and that method is still returning `2`. You must call the above method once that method is known to return `1`.

EDIT: Update after getting more information.

Take a look at the reference material for `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` ([Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/c:objc(pl)NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate)). It details how you should handle changes in data with respect to a `UITableView`. Basically remove the `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` from your edit method, and instead perform the tableView update in the appropriate delegate method. Something along these lines should help you (taken from the above reference):

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}
```

You probably don't need to handle each case. The `NSFetchedResultsController` reference is also quite helpful ([Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSFetchedResultsController/delegate)).

Comment: Forgive me for not fully understanding. But I know that I do call the line you mention, it looks like it's the same even. But where would I put numberOfRows: inSection?

Comment: I've updated my answer to add more detail about the method I'm inquiring about. Have you implemented this method: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:

Comment: Oh yes, I've not added that to my original post.

Comment: So you need to ensure that the `sections` array is also updated before you call the `deleteRows` method.

Comment: Ah. Just to make sure I'm on the right path. I would need to declare sections outside the function so that I can call it in my editActionsForRowAtIndexPath function as well, correct?

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help :)

Comment: Yes, `sections` is your data source, so you should be making modifications to it in your `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` (or triggering code that ends up changing it). And no problem!

Comment: So maybe I can bother you to spoon feed me this one. I was trying to edit the section, but when I declare it outside the func, in the class I can't figure out how to do something like removeAtIndex. I'm not sure how to declare the variable. I tried NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, but I can't find a way to remove it from there.

Comment: Can you add code for how you initially populate your sections array? I'm having trouble establishing the relationship between your sections array and your moc.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know obj-c... and I'm not sure I understand what is being said. But I'm sure for anyone else needing help this is probably enough and I want you to get the points for your effort so I'm going to mark you as having answered it and just keep searching the internet for my answer. Thank you so much for you effort!

Comment: Basically you need to set the delegate of your `frc` to your view controller (which you've done), and then implement the (long signatured) method I've outlined above. You need to call `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` in the above method, instead of the edit method (where you're calling it now).

Answer (score 0):

I GOT IT!!! But it is all thanks to Mark, he told me what I needed to do. And after googling a few things I was able to find the equivalent in swift. I just wanted to post my final code so anyone else needing the final result had it too!
Thank you again Mark, I spent a week spinning my wheels on this one thing.

I moved the `self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)` inside of `internal func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?)`

Here is the full view controller code

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ListTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
var frc: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "TableBackground"))
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
    self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    checkAnyList()

    frc = getFCR()
    frc.delegate = self

    do {
        try frc.performFetch()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to perform inital fetch")
    }

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    //self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = true

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    checkAnyList()

    frc = getFCR()
    frc.delegate = self

    do {
        try frc.performFetch()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to perform inital fetch")
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    if let sections = frc.sections {
        return sections.count
    }

    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if let sections = frc.sections {
        let currentSection = sections[section]
        return currentSection.numberOfObjects
    }

    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("listCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ListTableViewCell

    let list = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Lists

    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 78, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    cell.listNameLabel.text = list.name
    cell.listIconImage.image = UIImage(data: (list.image)!)
    //listCellReturn.itemCountLabel.text = "Items: \(listItemCount[indexPath.row])"

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in

        let request = self.fetchRequest()
        var fetchResults = [AnyObject]()

        do {
            fetchResults = try self.moc.executeFetchRequest(request)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Fetching Data to Delete Failed")
        }

        self.moc.deleteObject(fetchResults[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject)
        fetchResults.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

        do {
            try self.moc.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to Save after Delete")
        }

    }

    let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Edit") { (action, indexPath) in

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("newList", sender: tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath))

    }

    edit.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 84/255, green: 200/255, blue: 214/255, alpha: 1)

    return [delete, edit]

}

internal func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    if (type == NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete) {
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }

}

func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Lists")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    return fetchRequest

}

func getFCR() -> NSFetchedResultsController {

    frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    return frc

}

func checkAnyList() {

    var exists: Bool = false

    let fetchReq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Lists")
    let pred = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "name", "Any List")
    fetchReq.predicate = pred

    do {
        let check = try moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchReq)
        for rec in check {
            if let name = rec.valueForKey("name") {
                if (name as! String == "Any List") {
                    exists = true
                }
            }
        }

        if (exists == false) {
            let entityDesc = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Lists", inManagedObjectContext: moc)
            let list = Lists(entity: entityDesc!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)

            list.name = "Any List"
            list.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "Any List")!)

            do {
                try moc.save()
            } catch {
                fatalError("New list save failed")
            }
        }
    } catch {
        fatalError("Error checking for Any List")
    }

}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}
*/

// MARK: - Navigation

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if let _ = sender as? UITableViewCell {
        let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)

        let itemCont : AddListViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AddListViewController
        let list : Lists = self.frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! Lists
        itemCont.list = list
    }

}
```

}